# Html5 Canvas "Composite Layers" causing long frames

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, canvas, requestanimationframe

I have a javascript client that runs on a web page, drawing with *requestAnimationFrame* to the canvas and communicating via *websockets* to my NodeJS backend server (using the 'ws' module on the server side).

Profiling with Chrome DevTools, it seems that the combined time for scripting, rendering, & drawing each frame is only at maximum a few milliseconds. Yet there's still jank -- long frames from 20 - 40ms.

The timeline shows that in almost all of these cases there is a **"response"** that exceeds the length of the frame and/or a **"Composite Layers"** that occurs towards the end too.

[image: An example "long frame"]

This is essentially how I'm using *requestAnimationFrame*:

```
function drawGame() {

    // Drawing to gameCanvas from cacheCanvas
    // cacheCanvas is updated whenever an update is received from the server

    ctx.drawImage(cacheCanvas,
        // source rectangle
        0, 0,
        gameCanvas.width*2, gameCanvas.height*2,

        // destination
        100, 100,
        gameCanvas.width*2, gameCanvas.height*2
    );

    requestAnimationFrame(drawGame);
}

requestAnimationFrame(drawGame);
```

The server sends updates using setInterval() at 60hz. When a message is received from the server, the client immediately draws it. I suspect that this timing may be incorrect in conjunction with requestAnimationFrame, and is leading to the composite layers at the end of the frame.

Even so, I'm confused as to why there is so much idle time in-between scripting and "composite layers" for each frame. 
So...

- Is there a way to control when "composite layers" is called?
- Should I be saving the data from each update message and only drawing it   at the beginning of the next animation frame?
- What is the "response" referring to?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having this exact issue right now, did you ever find the cause? I'm using Chrome Canary Version 65.0.3322.3 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

The version of Chrome, rendering options, and video drivers may all affect this.  Post that information with your question. Also try searching on the Chromium bug list.

You can also try the latest dev build of Firefox which is supposed to have better performance by using multiple processes.

To determine whether server responses etc. have anything to do with performance, remove them and use fake data from the client only as a test.

Answer (score 0):

I think you hit on some of the problems, there.

### Solutioning:

Let's talk about potential solutions as a TLDR, and then explain how I get there.

1. Cache your messages to a buffer (eg: push them into an array), when the socket sends data; draw the buffered messages in the next animation frame; clear the buffer (or at least the ones that have been drawn), to await the next set of messages. Don't do heavy processing (drawing is one of the heaviest possible) on the main thread during I/O event handling.
2. a. If this is still not good enough, move the WebSocket (and data parsing, etc) into a WebWorker, and get the data handling off of the main thread.

   b. If **2a** is still not good enough, *also* make your canvas an [OffscreenCanvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas) which animates in the worker, and draws to a `"bitmap"` context (not "2d") on the main thread... **or** just have a "2d" canvas (or whatever you are using) on the front end and use [.transferControlToOffscreen()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/transferControlToOffscreen) to move the draw calls into the WebWorker

   c. regardless of solution in **2b**, continue to draw based on animationFrame, not whenever a WebSocket hands you data, if animation is at all important (if you are just updating a bar chart with new data every few seconds, none of any of this, including Chrome's complaints, matters)
3. You have a weird thing going on where you are only drawing portions of your canvas images, and you don't explain why... but if `ctx` belongs to `gameCanvas` and you are drawing to `100, 100, canvas.width * 2, canvas.height * 2` then something is off, because you are drawing to 2x the size of the canvas, and showing the top-left quadrant of the drawing, with a padding-top and padding-left of 100px... and that seems like a lot of waste (though it's not actually going to make you pay for all of the missed draw calls, checking the bounds is something you should be doing, yourself). Of course, if `ctx` isn't owned by `gameCanvas` and `ctx.canvas.width` is actually `100px + 2 * gameCanvas.width` then feel free to disregard all of #3.

This isn't guaranteed to solve all of your problems, but I do think these go a long way to smoothing out performance, by decoupling WebSocket and data parsing from your actual drawing performance... and preventing duplicate drawing actions (where one is potentially delayed by the other).

### Justification:

Ultimately, I think these problems comes down to the following:

- frame-pacing
- browser animation-frame scheduling
- timing of network handling
- time spent on main thread, during event callbacks

First, it sounds like your frame-pacing is off, and that will show up in Chrome's complaints. If you're comfortable with frame-pacing, skip the following paragraph.

> If you aren't familiar with the concept of frame-pacing, imagine that you are running at a solid 30fps (~33.3ms/frame), but some frames take, say 30fps, and some frames take 36ms... in that regard, while the average framerate might still be correctly described as 30fps, in human experience, some of your frames are now 20% longer than other frames (30ms followed by 36ms), and your eye notices the judder; presuming your animation requests were aiming for 30fps (probably 60+), then Chrome is going to highlight every frame that pushes longer than the 33.3ms time (or ~16.6ms for 60fps).

The next thing to understand is that `requestAnimationFrame` tries as hard as it can to lock itself to your monitor's refresh rate (or clean fractions thereof); back to the frame-pacing. But here's the problem, because in your case, this canvas is on the main thread (and I presume your websocket... and the initial paint for the other canvas...) all of these things are threatening to push the timing of your animation callback off. Consider a `setTimeout(f, 100)` It seems like `f` will run in exactly 100ms. But that's not true. It's guaranteed to run at some point, at least 100ms from now. If 99.8ms from now, a 10.2ms process starts running, then `f` won't run for 110ms, even if it was scheduled for 100ms.
In reality, we are talking about 60fps, or 120fps, or 144fps, or 165fps. This monitor is 144Hz, so I would expect 144fps or 72fps or 36fps updates, but even assuming the lax 30fps, the problem is that the timing is really fragile. A 4ms update, if it happens at the wrong time (ie: right before an animation callback is scheduled to run) is going to mess up your pacing, and show up on that Chrome timeline as a warning (that 4ms is a 10%+ delay for 30fps, it's 20%+ for 60fps, etc). This is also why your idle times are going to be *huge*. It's sitting and waiting and doing nothing... and just before it's ready to run the next animation frame at the perfect time to fit in with your screen refresh... a WebSocket message comes in, and then you do a billion things (like drawing in a 2D canvas is a huge `for` loop, even if it's hidden by the API) in that event, which delays the calling of the animation frame.

The last two I will sum up like this:
In JS, there is a saying... "Do not block the main thread". It's not really a saying. It's a state of being; a way of life. Do. Not. Block. The. Thread. Drawing pixels on a canvas (which is later going to have its pixels drawn on another canvas), and doing that inside of an event callback, is the *epitome* of blocking the main thread. It would be like having a 3,000 line long function run on `window.onscroll` or `window.onmousemove`. It doesn't matter how fast your PC is, your page performance is going to tank. In your handler, especially if it is an oft-fired handler, do the bare minimum to prep the data, store the data for later, and either return if you are set up to poll for this data (like a game loop), or schedule something `setTimeout(f, 0)` or `Promise.resolve().then(f)` or `requestIdleCallback` (if it's a low-importance thing), etc, to look at it later.

To sum it up, performance is critical, but performance isn't just the time it takes to run, it's also the precision of the time when it runs. Keep things off the main thread, so that this time can stay as accurate as possible.